# How to access Vue prototype property from typescript component

Tags: typescript, vuejs2

I'm migrating my vuejs app to typescript for better maintanability. Here is my problem:

I created a `TokenService` to retrieve the admin's token from the local storage :

```
// token.service.js

/*
  Get the admin's token from localstorage.
  @return {object} The token
*/
getToken() {
  return localStorage.getItem("token")
}
```

To have the service available in all the components without having to import it in each one of them, I added the service to the `Vue.prototype` :

```
// main.js

Vue.prototype.$tokenService = TokenService
```

But when I try to access the `this.$tokenService` from my component `AdminWorkerPage` written in typescript, I get the error: *TS2339: Property '$tokenService' does not exist on type 'AdminWorkerPage'.*

```
// AdminWorkerPage.ts

import { Vue, Component, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator'

@Component({})
export default class AdminWorkerPage extends Vue {

  broadcast(): Promise<void> {
    token: this.$tokenService.getToken() // <-- $tokenService used here !
    ...
  }
}
```

But when my file was written in javascript, I had no problem.

How can I tell the compiler that the property exists in the component?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to [augment the Vue type](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Augmenting-Types-for-Use-with-Plugins):

```
// token-service.d.ts

import Vue from 'vue'
import TokenService from '../path/to/token-service'

declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  interface Vue {
    $tokenService: TokenService
  }
}
```

Comment: Does it matters where do i put this file in my project structure?

Comment: I typically put type declaration files in a `types` directory in the project's root folder.